# Are there Java SOAP transport layer Exceptions?

Tags: java, soap, exception

Imagine two super-powers who are not talking to each other and are on the brink of war. There is no longer any dialog between them.

There is an IT red phone equivalent to avoid war: a Java web service.

The SOAP message is sent.

Is there a way for the sender to be certain the message was received even if he did not obtain a response?

Are there Java SOAP transport layer exceptions that can provide that info?

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2440/aeqey.html) on Oracle's site specifies that the default transport layer for SOAP follows the same model as HTTP.

> Although SOAP messages can be sent using any number of protocols, the SOAP specification defines only the binding with HTTP. SOAP uses the HTTP request/response message model.

Unless you're using some other protocol to send the message, I'd wager that you will have a mechanism to detect whether the message was received, since HTTP does that.  Where and how you detect that would probably depend on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific on what you are using this for.

I would use Wireshark or some other sniffer that gives you all of the information on the packets, who is listening, and what protocols they are using.